# segmentation fault on malloc initializating 2d-array

Tags: arrays, c, memory, segmentation-fault, malloc

My program fails because of a segmentation fault. Using gdb i could see that the trouble was when i was initializing a 2d-array in my function.

My compiler flags were `-Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -Wconversion -std=gnu11`

This is the function i'm using. The error raises on line 4. I don't understand why it breaks there, im fairly a beginner to C.

```
1 char ** get_categories_names(char * file_route, unsigned int maximum_categories) {
2     unsigned int category_counter = 0;
3
4     char ** categories_list = (char **)malloc(maximum_categories * sizeof(char *));
5     char * category = "";
6     FILE * categories_config;
7     categories_config = fopen(file_route, "r");
8
9     if (categories_config == NULL)
10    {
11            perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
12            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
13    }
14
15    while (fgets(category, 255, categories_config) && category_counter < maximum_categories) {
16            printf("%d", category_counter);
17            categories_list[category_counter] = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
18            category[strcspn(category, "\n")] = 0;
19            categories_list[category_counter] = category;
20            category_counter++;
21    }
22    fclose(categories_config);
23    return categories_list;
```

This is the gdb result:

```
(gdb) step
11              char ** categories_list = (char **)malloc(maximum_categories * sizeof(char *));
(gdb) step
__GI___libc_malloc (bytes=40) at malloc.c:3028
3028    malloc.c: No existe el archivo o el directorio.
```

And this is the text file i was reading to:

```
horror
mystery
FPS
memes
comedy
```

Comment: How large is `maximum_categories`?

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: I don't think your seg fault is because of `malloc()`. It's `fgets(category, 255, categories_config)`. `category` declared is a pointer to a string literal `""`. You cant' overwrite that. Declare it as `char category[255}` instead

Comment: .. but other bugs come afterwards, like `categories_list[category_counter] = category;` You can't copy strings like that.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt added gdb step results so you can see better my error

Comment: To expound upon what @IngoLeonhardt posted, where is the memory that the file contents get read into?

Comment: @fas just an unsigned integer. the value is 5.

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory, it will tell you where.

Comment: if your program really crashes in the first `malloc()` and `maximum_categories` has a sensible value (esp. >0) the real reason is somewhere before the call to `get_categroy_names()`, like writing out of bounds of another allocated array. I can recommend valgrind too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues. I'll try to fix then in your code adding comments about the reasons. Please note that I didn't compile so there might be some typos

```
char ** get_categories_names(char * file_route, unsigned int maximum_categories) {
     unsigned int category_counter = 0;

     // don't cast the result of malloc
     char ** categories_list = malloc(maximum_categories * sizeof(char *));
     // declare category as array to provide memory for fgets()
     char category[255];
     FILE * categories_config;
     categories_config = fopen(file_route, "r");

     if (categories_config == NULL)
     {
           perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

     // use sizeof array so you don't have to repeat array size
     while (fgets(category, sizeof category, categories_config) && category_counter < maximum_categories) {
              printf("%d", category_counter);
              
              category[strcspn(category, "\n")] = 0;
              // alloc the right size -- sizeof( char ) is always 1 and can be omitted
              categories_list[category_counter] = malloc(strlen(category)+1);
              // copy strings w/ strcpy()
              strcpy(categories_list[category_counter], category);
              // the two commands above could be replaced by
              //categories_list[category_counter] = strdup(category);
              category_counter++;
      }
      fclose(categories_config);
      return categories_list;
```

Besides, `malloc()` could return `NULL`. That should be checked too

Comment: this really helped, thanks! btw, any reason why gdb would stop on the array allocation? instead inside the while when i was debugging, that really confused me

Comment: glad i could help. I'm sorry but with this information I can't say anything about what you've experienced with gdb. Is still recommed tou run your program with valgrind too. That might show some errors that don't lead to an observable problem. Due to the nature of Undefined Behaviour everything seems to work although your code is broken

Answer (score 1):

regarding;

```
(gdb) step
11              char ** categories_list = (char **)malloc(maximum_categories * sizeof(char *));
(gdb) step
__GI___libc_malloc (bytes=40) at malloc.c:3028
3028    malloc.c: No existe el archivo o el directorio.
```

This is NOT saying that a seg fault event occurred.

Rather, it is saying that you do not have the source code for 'malloc.c' visible to `gdb`

To avoid this kind of problem, suggest:

```
(gdb) step
11              char ** categories_list = (char **)malloc(maximum_categories * sizeof(char *));
(gdb) next
```

which will exec the call to `malloc()`, but not stop until the next statement in your code